# if for return value of NSObject in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code:

```
func onDoubleTap(sender:AnyObject) {
var StringBool = Swapper.getSwapperValue
if StringBool == "false"{...}
```

`Swapper` is another class, subclassing `NSObject`. `getSwapperValue` is function, which returns a `false` value of variable. But with this code, I get an error: `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Swapper -> () -> NSString' and 'String'`

Comment: @EricD. yes, ofc. So, im not using string as Bools. "false" value - is a String value :) Code here: 
class Swapper: NSObject{
func getSwapperValue() -> NSString {
var swapper = "false"
return swapper
}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error message

```
'Swapper -> () -> NSString' and 'String'
```

The type of the right side of `==` is `String`, the type of the left side is `Swapper -> () -> NSString` which is a function type - not a string of any sort.  Functions in Swift are first class types which means you can treat them like an ordinary variable and my guess is that that is what you are doing - `Swapper.getSwapperValue` is a function not a property.  Try writing

```
var stringBool = Swapper.getSwapperValue()
```

or if Swapper is a class and `getSwapperValue` is not a class function

```
var stringBool = Swapper().getSwapperValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

So, i resolved my problem here:

I created a variable in NSObject class named **swapper1**.

and here's my code: `var swapa = Swapper().swapper1`
and convert same.